# iOS 13 UIKit What to do if viewWillAppear would not work?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I've noticed that once I have two modal VC presented at the same time (VC2 over VC1) and need to dismiss the one that is beneath(VC1), I accidentally dismiss the top one(VC2). As an alternative, I've put logic on viewWillAppear to determine if the VC1 would be still needed once VC2 dismiss from the screen, however, that is not the most reliable method. Any clue if iOS 13 got something new to handle such a scenario?
The VC2 is being presented overFullScreen, regretfully, observers did not do me any good. Still buggy.
Any tips or tricks would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to close `VC1` and `VC2` from `VC2`. What you can do is inside of `viewWillDisappear` of `VC2` you can close `VC1`. Unfortunately you cannot close `VC1` without closing `VC2`.

So what you will have is:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    //if you don't want to close VC1 everytime, add a condition here
    presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you!